# Selenium can't click on a element in an iframe

Tags: python, selenium

So im trying to click a button in an iframe but it just errors saying that the button can't be found.

```
recaptcha = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(recaptcha)

submit1 = driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-anchor')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(submit1)
actions.click(submit1).perform()

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button').click()
```

On the last line I try to get an element by id `recaptcha-audio-button`.
As I said above it just errors with that it can't find it.

The website that I am trying to do this with is: https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

Why can't I click this button?

Thanks, Ira.

**EDIT**
Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 62, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button').click()
  File "/home/ira/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/home/ira/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/ira/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ira/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could easily copy and test it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will edit the message with the error.  and send a link to the full code.

https://pastebin.com/2FdWkwVP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element is in different iframe so you can do:

- switch to main window
- find all iframes and switch to second iframe
- find and click your button

Code:

```
# go back to main window
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# find all frames and switch to second frame
all_frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(all_frames[1])

driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button').click()
```

---

Minimal working code so everyone can copy and test it

```
import selenium.webdriver
import time

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/')

recaptcha = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(recaptcha)

submit1 = driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-anchor')

actions = selenium.webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(submit1)
actions.click(submit1).perform()

time.sleep(3)

# go back to main window
driver.switch_to.default_content()

# find all frames and switch to second frame
all_frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(all_frames[1])

driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button').click()
```